# 2D character with baseball bat implementation in Unity

Tags: unity

I'm making a 2D baseball game in Unity and I'd like to know how the player and the bat should be connected. For instance, if I use single sprite for both the player and the bat, then how should the collision between the bat and the ball be detected?

Comment: This question might get closed, but I would also like to hear the answer

Comment: To Evorlor's point, this does seem a bit too specific. I think it would be a valuable question if it was generalized across "Swinging Objects in 2D".

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple you can just use a fixed collider (as a component of your player or of any of its children so it moves with it) and enable it for a short time when your player swings the bat then immediately disable it.
There are several ways to do it other than all-code with timers. For example if you have an animation (Animation not Animator) that plays when your player swings, you can simply add a curve for the BoxCollider.Enabled value (assuming your collider is BoxCollider).

[image]

In the picture above the collider will be enabled between 0.20 and 0.43 as the entered values are, in order from the left: false, true, false, false. (Last false isn't needed but just to be safe).

Once you've done this, detecting the collision is done the standard way. [Here's a nice tutorial](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/unity-3d-collisions-basics/114) in case you need.